# Finding all words between delimiters using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have researched this question and studied up on regex but I still can't get this.

I need to find all words from a given txt file between two delimiters. The delimiters are:

```
** START **

** END **
```

It seems pretty basic but I haven't been able to get it. This is what I have so far,

```
def extract_words(file):
    infile = open(file, 'r', encoding="utf-8").readlines()
    fileString = ""
    for line in infile:
        fileString += line
        for matchedtext in re.findall(r'(?<=\D{2}\sSTART\s\D{2}).*?(?=\D{2}\sEND\s\D{2)', fileString):
            print(matchedtext)
```

Example of expected operation

inputFile.txt

> {
>   hello here is some text don't extract these words ** START ** start extracting these words though. test 1 2 3 4 hello world ** END ** these words shouldn't be extracted.
>   }

would result in:

```
start extracting these words though. test 1 2 3 4 hello world
```

Could someone please explain where I am going wrong with this and how to fix?

Comment: Please give examples of input and expected match pattern in said input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a right curly brace `}` on your *Lookahead* and `.*?` here is currently matching any character (*except newline*), you need to use the `s` (*DOTALL*) modifier to force the dot to match any character, including newline.

```
(?=\D{2}\sEND\s\D{2 )
                   ^ missing right curly brace
```

You can use the following here.

```
re.findall(r'(?s)(?<=\D{2}\sSTART\s\D{2}).*?(?=\D{2}\sEND\s\D{2})', fileString)
```

Also, be aware that `\D` matches anything except a digit and if you have these delimiters preceded by or followed by letters for example, it could possibly match between them also. I would use `\*{2}` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked. So it was missing all of the other lines due to not have the DOTALL modifier?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is ill-formed.  There's a `}` missing from the last `\D{3}`:

```
r'(?<=\D{3}\sSTART\s\D{3}).*?(?=\D{3}\sEND\s\D{3})'
                                                ^ missing
```